#  Passing URL with parameter  

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am passing url with some string value and `NSInteger` value in this `url` but when I put `breakpoint` on this and I tab on trace then it show me this message `exc-bad-access` in `url` I given bold please see that 'bold' I want to pass there value:
`[ NSInteger day,NSInteger day1,NSString *fromDate1, NSString *fromDate1,NSString *OriginCode,NSString *DestinCode]`.

I get all value on `url` when I put the `breakpoint` but when I step into `breakpoint` my app crashes, why it crash? Help me. Where am I wrong?

```
-(void)sendRequest

{    








   stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com?AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24ButtonSubmit=Search%20For%20Flights%20&AvailabilitySeast=",day,day1,DestinCode,"2011-09","2011-09",OriginCode];
   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bookairways tickt.com/Sales/FRSearch.aspx?AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24ButtonSubmit=Search%20For%20Flights%20&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay1=**%i**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDay2=**%i**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketDestination1=**%@**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth1=**%@**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketMonth2=**%@**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListMarketOrigin1=**%@**&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_ADT=1&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_CHD=0&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT=0&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24RadioButtonFlowSelector=FlightAndCar&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24RadioButtonMarketStructure=RoundTrip&AvailabilitySearchInputFRSearchView%24discountPax=0&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTTARGET=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUBMGRkg4UKvNNb1NbM14%2F2n9zUxhNQ%2B%2BA%3D&errorlist=",day,day1,DestinCode,fromDate1,fromDate2,OriginCode];
   //urlString=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   NSLog(@"************url:%@",url);

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                timeoutInterval:60.0];
   NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
   if (theConnection) {
      webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
      NSLog(@"%@",webData);
   } else {

   }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harish this will help u to in creating the url check this our http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes
like this

```
 NSString *template = @"appigotodo://com.example.xyzapp/import?name=%@&note=%@&due-date=%@&priority=%@&repeat=%@";
NSString *name = @"Buy%20some%20milk";
NSString *note = @"Stop%20on%20the%20way%20home%20from%20work.";
NSString *dueDate = @"2009-07-16";
NSString *priority = @"1";
NSString *repeat = @"101";
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:template, name, note, dueDate, priority, repeat];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
```

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Answer (score 2):

make your url properly like this:-

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[*yourstring* stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The URL has many % symbols that are not being used as placeholders. The % symbols that are not between '**' in your code need to be escaped like so: %%. In other words, `SearchInputFRSearchView%24Button` should be `SearchInputFRSearchView%%24Button`.
2. You are using %i to put integers into your string. You should be using %d instead.

Comment: check it out above  once again i amke change in link but even not get solve .How can i do this